# Conduction angle in three-phase rectifier

Tags: mosfet, rectifier, theory

In a standard three-phase bridge rectifier, which consists of 6 diodes, each diode (or thyristor) conducts 120º of the full 360º period. I have built a synchronous rectifier (for research purposes), which is controlled by microcontroller, and found out that I can extend this angle by 15º, so each MOSFET now conducts 135º. For example, upper leg MOSFET of the phase 1 now conducts from 22.5º to 157.5º, instead of the usual range from 30º to 150º). However, past this point (wider angle) the system goes into a short-circuit. Can someone explain how is this limit determined?